# When and when not to use an A/A test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, experiment-design

I'm curious about the circumstances under which an A/A test is a appropriate, vs. when it is not.

Here is my current understanding:

- A/A testing is an empirical method, and the point is to understand the variance of a metric without a treatment (A/A).
- This will allow us to calculate the confidence interval for our experimental findings.
- If the sample values are normally distributed, instead of an A/A test I can make assumptions about the population parameters, and estimate the variance analytically. (?)

If the above is true, is there any reason to **not** use an A/A test?  Some things that come to mind are 1. Time to run an A/A test, 2. Computation and resources, 3.  It's not feasible for some other reason.  But is there any statistical/mathematical reason to not use an A/A test, if you can?

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of an A/A test.  In these sorts of tests, would you show *the same* variant to two different groups?

Comment: @DemetriPananos - An A/A test is where you essentially have a Control vs Control experiment- neither group receives a treatment.  This allows you to compute the variance empirically

Comment: I still don't see the point of two groups.  If I have a single group and a desired outcome, I can estimate the variance of that outcome from that group using the sample variance. If I wanted an estimate of the variance of the statistic (e.g. the variance of the sampling distribution of the mean) I can use the standard error.  Could you point me towards something I can read on the topic of A/A tests so that I can be more helpful?

Comment: @DemetriPananos - Good point and maybe I am not understanding the concept correctly- attempting to self-learn and trying to get some clarity.  Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wzs1KFldiUE.  0:28 - "At Google, what we found was that even for some of the simple metrics, the analytical estimate of the variance ended up being an **underestimate**... because of that we shifted to using A/A experiments across the board to estimate the empirical variability of all our metrics."  This is from the Udacity A/B Testing course: https://www.udacity.com/course/ab-testing--ud257. Thanks for helping here